# FancyTree partially selecting all parent nodes when selecting a node (similar to multi-hier select mode but in single select mode)

Tags: fancytree

I wanted to give a better visual cue to the user when selecting a child node in FancyTree similar to the multi-hier select mode but allowing the user to only select one node at a time, so when the user checks the checkbox of a node I need all parent nodes to be 1) partially selected and 2) highlighted, how can I achieve this?